# What is "Consumer utilisation" in RabbitMQ, and how does it relate to prefetch count?

Tags: java, rabbitmq

What is Consumer Utilization (shown in the RabbitMQ management console) in RabbitMQ? Is it the percentage the consumers utilize the RabbitMQ by consuming the messages? Or have I misunderstood it? If so how to make the consumers best utilize the RabbitMQ for 100%? Because, I couldn't see any increase in % when I increase the consumers, but only a fraction of seconds on the moment a new consumer is started. I could not make lots from the small explanation provided in tool-tip.

Besides, the tooltip doc says the prefetch count someway influences the consumer utilization, so is there a formula kind to fix the numbers?

```
so many consumers = this many fetch counts
```

(or)

```
time taken by a consumer to process a messages = this many fetch count
```

Comment: you have at least 2 distinct questions here: rabbitmq consumer utilization and prefetch. please keep your question limited to 1 specific subject. open a new question for the second one

Comment: It might be better to ask this question here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users

Answer (score 5):

The definition of consumer utilisation is the proportion of time that a queue's consumers could take new messages.

Increasing the prefetch limit will result in increases in consumer utilisation.

See [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2014/04/14/finding-bottlenecks-with-rabbitmq-3-3/) for more info.

The page linked above also contains the author's observations on the correlation between prefetch limit and consumer utilisation.